# React-Native: Flatlist and Sectionlist are throwing an exception when an empty array is passed in ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

Following is my `Flatlist` code,

```
 <FlatList
      data={allRequestsArr}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderItems(item, index)}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
      onEndReached={this.loadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
      initialNumToRender={allRequestsArr.length}
      ListEmptyComponent={this.renderEmptyResultContent}
 />
```

when ever `allRequestsArr` is and empty array, getting following exception,

[image]

This is happening only in `ios`(with both `Flatlist` and `SectionList`). In android `ListEmptyComponent` is being called as usual.

Can anybody let me know what's wrong with the code?.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it would have been an empty array then no error would have thrown, the problem is either value is undefined that is passed or NAN ,

so try this :

```
<FlatList
      data={allRequestsArr?allRequestsArr:[]}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderItems(item, index)}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
      onEndReached={this.loadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
      initialNumToRender={allRequestsArr.length}
      ListEmptyComponent={this.renderEmptyResultContent}
 />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have directly given an empty array like this `data={ [] }`, But still it's throwing same error.